# How to optimize my code for the Kattis Accounting Question?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing this [Kattis accounting question](https://open.kattis.com/problems/bokforing) but at test case 10, it has the error Time limit exceeded.

How can I optimize my code to make it run faster?

Here's the question!

> Erika the economist studies economic inequality. Her model starts in a
> situation where everybody has the same amount of money. After that,
> people’s wealth changes in various complicated ways.
>
> Erika needs to run a simulation a large number of times to check if
> her model works. The simulation consists of  people, each of whom
> begins with  kroners. Then  events happen, of three different types:
>
> An event of type “SET  ” means that the th person’s wealth is set to .
>
> An event of type “RESTART ” means that the simulation is restarted,
> and everybody’s wealth is set to .
>
> An event of type “PRINT ” reports the current wealth of the th person.
>
> Unfortunately, Erika’s current implementation is very slow; it takes
> far too much time to keep track of how much money everybody has. She
> decides to use her algorithmic insights to speed up the simulation.
>
> Input The first line includes two integers  and , where  and . The
> following  lines each start with a string that is either “SET”,
> “RESTART”, or “PRINT”. There is guaranteed to be at least one event of
> type “PRINT”.
>
> If the string is “SET” then it is followed by two integers  and  with
> and . If the string is “RESTART” then it is followed by an integer
> with . If the string is “PRINT” then it is followed by an integer
> with .
>
> Output For each event of type “PRINT”, write the th person’s capital.
>
> Sample Input 1: 
>  3 5 
>  SET 1 7 
>  PRINT 1 
>  PRINT 2 
> RESTART 33 
>  PRINT 1
>
> Sample Output 1: 
>  7 
>  0 
>  33
>
> Sample Input 2: 
>  5 7 
>  RESTART 5 
>  SET 3 7 
>  PRINT 1 
> PRINT 2 
>  PRINT 3 
>  PRINT 4 
>  PRINT 5
>
> Sample Output 2: 
>  5 
>  5 
>  7 
>  5 
>  5

```
# print("Enter 2 numbers")
n, q = map(int, input().split())

# print(n , q)

people = {}

def createPeople(n):
    for i in range(n):
        number = i+1
        people[number] = 0
    return people

def restart(n,new):
    for i in range(n):
        number = i+1
        people[number] = new
    return people

def setPeople(d ,id , number):
    d[id] = number
    return d
    # return d.update({id: number})

def logic(n,dict,q):
    
    for i in range(q):
        # print("enter Command")
        r = input()
        r = r.split()
        # print("r" ,r)
        if r[0] == "SET":
            # print(people , "People list")
            abc = setPeople(dict, int(r[1]), int(r[2]))
            # print(list)

        elif r[0] == "RESTART":
            abc = restart(n, int(r[1]))
            
        elif r[0] == "PRINT":
            print(dict[int(r[1])])
    # return abc
people = createPeople(n)
# print(people)
test = logic(n,people,q)
```

Comment: Why are you using a global for `people`?  Your functions should create it locally, not try to reuse it.

Comment: Don't use `dict` for a variable name.  It's a basic builtin which is masked by a variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The input is too big to be doing anything linear, like looping over all of the people and setting their values by hand. If we have 10<sup>5</sup> queries and 10<sup>6</sup> people, the worst case scenario is resetting over and over again, 10<sup>11</sup> operations.

Easier is to keep a variable to track the baseline value after resets. Whenever a reset occurs, dump all entries in the dictionary and set the baseline to the specified value. Assume any further lookups for people that aren't in the dictionary to have the most recent baseline value. Now, all operations are O(1) and we can handle 10<sup>5</sup> queries linearly.

```py
people = {}
baseline = 0
n, q = map(int, input().split())

for _ in range(q):
    command, *args = input().split()

    if command == "SET":
        people[int(args[0])] = int(args[1])
    elif command == "RESTART":
        people.clear()
        baseline = int(args[0])
    elif command == "PRINT":
        print(people.get(int(args[0]), baseline))
```

As an aside, writing abstractions is great in a real program, but for these tiny code challenges I'd just focus on directly solving the problem. This reduces the potential for confusion with return values like `abc` that seem to have no clear purpose.

Per [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), use snake_case rather than camelCase in Python.